# How to define a shared enity and make other entitis have one to many relation to it in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want define a shared entity  like below:

```
class Image
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  FileName { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }     // image binary data
    ...
}
```

Because, I have multiple entities will have one to many relation to Image entity.

```
class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  ProductName { get; set; }
    List<Image> ProductAvatars { get; set; }
    ...
}

class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  CategoryName { get; set; }
    List<Image> CategoryAvatars { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I think Image entity is not belong to one specific entity(e.g. Product or Category), so define foreign keys in `Image` does not make sense. Should I add more association tables like below?

```
class ProductAvatars
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int ImageID { get; set; }   // it's a foreign key of Image entity
}

class CategoryAvatars
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int ImageID { get; set; }    // it's a foreign key of Image entity
}
```

How to achieve this? Please give me some advice, Thank you all!

Comment: If the `Image` does not belong to specific entity (i.e. one and the same image can be used for product and category), then this is classical many-to-many relationship, and yes, you need to create junction entities (tables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

You can use join types:

```
public class ProductImage {
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Image Image {get; set; }
}

public class CategoryImage {
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Image Image {get; set;
}
```

`Product` and `Category` wouldn't have `List<Image>`, but `List<ProductImage>` and `List<CategoryImage>`.

---

**OPTION 2**

Use two nullable FK columns, like so:

```
class Image
{

            public int ID { get; set; }
            public int? ProductId {get; set; } // by making the Id nullable, the FK is optional
            public Product Product { get; set;}
            public int? CategoryId { get; set;}
            public Category Category { get; set;}
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public int Length { get; set; }
            public byte[] Data { get; set; }     // image binary data

}
```

Comment: OPTION2 will make entity Image grows fast when there are more other entities relate to it in project. so, I prefer OPTION 1, and also @Ivan Stoev gives me a good idea.  Thank you both!